# Problem in accessing decision table through Flowable deployed as a Spring Boot Maven Dependency

Tags: camunda, bpmn, flowable, dmn

1. I have a flowable project(microservice) which has flowable-spring-boot-starter-rest in pom.xml, bpmn file is deployed under resources/processes directory.
2. I am accessing the above flowable REST APIs to start the process, complete the tasks and get the tasks through another micro-service.
3. Everything works fine with respect to bpmn. But I recently introduced Decision Table and added the dmn file under resources/processes directory of flowable project. (not sure dmn is getting deployed but bpmn is getting deployed)

I properly referred the Decision Table in flowable process modeler. There is no problem in this. The validation check has no errors. But when the task in the process comes to Decision Table, it throws "Exception : No decision found for key : <key_name_of_decision_table>".

My Process can access the decision table successfully if I use flowable-ui.war to run the flowable, but If I use flowable-spring-boot-starter-rest maven dependency this problem occurs.

I tried adding maven dependency for flowable-spring-boot-starter-dmn and flowable-dmn-model maven dependencies, nothing worked.

Do I need to configure or enable some properties of dmn in the application.properties? I have no clue now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deploy decision tables, you need to place them in the directory `resources/dmn` rather than `resources/process`. Also, you should ensure that the suffix is either `.dmn` or `.dmn.xml`.

You can use the [repository decision tables](https://documentation.flowable.com/latest/assets/core-swagger/dmn.html#/Decision%20Tables/listDecisionTables) endpoint to check if the deployment worked.

Please refer to the class [FlowableDmnProperties](https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine/blob/982be7e47facf17bb779571ba663bdf8f86947a3/modules/flowable-spring-boot/flowable-spring-boot-starters/flowable-spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/flowable/spring/boot/dmn/FlowableDmnProperties.java#L39) for more configuration options.